# Remove quotations with conditions

Tags: python

If I want to remove quotation marks from words such as these:

```
don't
hello'
world'
```

How do I make it so that I only remove quotations from the 2nd and 3rd one. i.e. I want to make so that I only strip quotations if it is NOT surrounded by two letters and to have an end result like this:

```
don't
hello
world
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
words = ["don't", "hello'", "world'"]
quotes = ["'", '"']
output = list()

for word in words:
    if word[-1] in quotes:
        word = word[: (len(word) - 1)] 
    output.append(word)

print output
#=> ["don't", "hello", "world"]
```

I'm assuming you'll also want to handle the case where the unwanted quote could be a also be double quote, `"`, in addition to a single quote. If not you could just use:

```
if word[-1] === "'":
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
string = "hello'"

if string[-1] == "'":
    string = string[:len(string) - 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `regex`, but it really doesn't require it. Let me know if this is an innacurate treatment of your problem, but it seems like you could do something along the lines of:

```
if not test_string.endswith("'"):
    test_string.replace("'", "")
```

If you really WANT to use `regex` (which might be a good choice depending on your application), you could do something like this:

```
import re
re.sub('(?:(?<=\w)[\'\"](?:\W))|(?:(?<=\W)[\'\"](?:\w))', '', test_string)
```